# Firestore compound query with map fields

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In my chat application, I store the participants of a chat as their UIDs in a `Map` so I can so I can do queries like this:

```
.whereEqualTo("participantUIDs.$currentUserUid", true)
.whereEqualTo("participantUIDs.$partnerUid", true)
```

The problem is when I try to use this with orderBy

```
.whereEqualTo("participantUIDs.$currentUserUid", true)
.orderBy("lastMessageSentTimestamp")
```

I have to create a custom index. But this index will contain that specific user UID and I can't create an index for every user in my app. How can I circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can order the documents on the client after an unordered query.  This should not be very taxing on the client app when the number of documents is less than 10,000.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> I can't create an index for every user in my app.

That's definitely not an option, as there are some limitations when it comes to Cloud Firestore indexes:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes

However, even if you manage to stay below these limits, that's not an option to manually create an index for each and every user that joins your app.

In my opinion, for your particular use-case, you should consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup. Meaning that you should create a `participantUIDs` collection where you should keep the lists for each user. This technique is called [denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore/) and is a common practice when it comes to NoSQL databases like Cloud Firestore or Firebase Realtime Database.

But remember, there is "no perfect database structure":

- [What is the correct way to structure this kind of data in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053768/what-is-the-correct-way-to-structure-this-kind-of-data-in-firestore/53057707)

It's a little old, but I think this video might  also help:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3KwKQddPoo

More info regarding why you need an index:

- [Why does this firestore query require an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790175/why-does-this-firestore-query-require-an-index)

**P.S.** You can also rely on Firebase Realtime Database when Cloud Firestore may become a little expensive. Both work really well together.

Info:

- [Array or Subcollection for storing events user uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596190/array-or-subcollection-for-storing-events-user-uploaded)

Comment: Hi Florian! Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?